# Prolog - sending text from menu(cycle) to text_item

Tags: user-interface, menu, prolog

This is my code:

```
   listaw1:-

 new(SS, dialog('text')),
 send(SS, display,new(W3, text('text'))),
 send(SS, append, new(N5,text_item('dfsdfsdf'))),

 send(SS, append, new(MCom,menu(nazwa_komponentu,cycle))),

 send_list(MCom, append, [some_text]),

  send(SS, append,
         button(ok, and(message(@prolog, function,
                                           MCom?selection,

                                           N5?selection),

                                           message(SS, destroy)))),
get(SS, confirm, Rval),
send(SS,open).

 function(MCom,N5):-send(MCom, append, N5).
```

I want to send chosen text option from menu(cycle) MCom to text_item blank row N5 by click ok button. Do you know how to do it? I tried using @prolog message and function...with send(A,append,B), but it doesn't works...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand much of your code (specially `message(SS, destroy))`: what's the purpose?), then forgive me if I post a misleading hint, but

```
...
send(SS, append,
  button(ok, message(@prolog, function, MCom, N5))),
...
```

paired with

```
function(MCom, N5):-
    get(MCom, selection, Selected),
    send(N5, selection, Selected).
```

seems to work. I get `some_text` in `N5`.

Comment: Yes it works ! Thank you very much! @message(SS, destroy)) - I want to close the window after 'ok' pressing.

Comment: Do you know, what should I do if I want to send some_text, like above...but to text_item in other dialog window? Is this possible?

Comment: Think about the variables referring to GUI objects as 'smart pointers'. AFAIK, you can also share them using the global database. But better design would be to properly connect objects using XPCE class objects.